# How do I stop Tomcat using shutdown.bat in app.on ("before-quit")?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I try to start and stop a Tomcat instance on Windows using Electron.

I have modified the `electron-quick-start` project to stop my Tomcat instance with a batch file which calls Tomcat's `shutdown.bat` when all Electron windows are closed or before my application exits.

However, when I close my application, there is no output from the `shutdownTomcat.on ("data", ...)` and `shutdownTomcat.on ("exit", ...)` listeners. The only output is from a `console.log ("Hello world")` from my `app.on ("before-quit", ...)`.

I chose this approach because I am new to Electron and want to test NodeJS' `spawn`'s behaviour.

When I use my code outside of the `app.on ()` listeners, the output is shown but my Tomcat instance is not being stopped. However, my `startTomcat.bat` file, which calls Tomcat's `startup.bat`, works without any problems.

I already read NodeJS' `childProcess`' documentation ("Spawning .bat and .cmd files on Windows"), but I cannot get it to work; which leads to my question, namely where the problem is and what I'm doing wrong.

My `Main.js` file I use for the main process:

```javascript
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const path = require('path');

const start = path.resolve("./start.bat");
const startTomcat = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', start], {
   cwd: process.cwd(),
   detached: true,
});

// ...

app.on('before-quit',()=> {
  const shutdownTomcat = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', stop], {
    detached: true
    //  stdio: 'ignore' 
  });

  shutdownTomcat.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log("This data won't show up...", data);

  });

  shutdownTomcat.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString());
  });

  shutdownTomcat.on('exit', (code) => {
    console.log(`Child Shutdown Tomcat exited with code ${code}`);
  });

  console.log("Hello World");
});
```

And finally, the batch file (`stop.bat`) I'm using to call Tomcat's `shutdown.bat`:

```
cd /D "%~dp0"
cd "..\\apache-tomcat\\bin"
call shutdown.bat
```

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your electron application is already terminated by the time your events would have fired. Therefore there is no longer reference to your spawned process and listeners.

You can try `event.preventDefault()` to cancel the app quitting. Then you can explicitly `app.quit()` once you are done (but beware of infinitely looping through your before-quit listener; you may remove it or `app.exit(0)`).